# Syntax error for 'OR'

Tags: sql-server, syntax

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 67
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'OR'.

```
WHERE cast (INVOICEDATE as date)>=@FROMDATE
  AND InvoiceStatusID=('IN' OR 'OR')
  AND SALESHEADER.ParentAccountID NOT IN (SELECT ACCOUNTID FROM [YVFSQL-REPORT].DBO.ExcludedAccounts where WarehouseID=1)
   AND SALESHEADER.ParentAccountID NOT IN (SELECT ACCOUNTID FROM GetProducePartnerAccountID_ByWarehouseID(1))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my understanding below syntax line is looking for exact match.

```
InvoiceStatusID=('IN' OR 'OR')
```

You can use IN syntax as IN is shorthand for multiple OR.

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table_name
WHERE column_name IN (value1, value2, ....);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use equals = to compare multiple values. It's a boolean expression. Use IN instead.

```
WHERE cast (INVOICEDATE as date)>=@FROMDATE AND InvoiceStatusID IN ('IN', 'OR')
```

Comment: OR use `(InvoiceStatusID = 'IN' OR InvoiceStatusID = 'OR')` :-D

Answer (score 0):

would like to re-write this into

1) use IN for invoicestatus to correct the issue
2) and use NOT EXISTS over inner join rather than two NOT IN Subqueries

```
WHERE cast (INVOICEDATE as date)>=@FROMDATE
  AND InvoiceStatusID in ('IN','OR')
  AND NOT EXISTS
       (SELECT 1 FROM [YVFSQL-REPORT].DBO.ExcludedAccounts T1
         INNER JOIN GetProducePartnerAccountID_ByWarehouseID(1) T2 
            ON
              T1.ACCOUNTID  = T2.ACCOUNTID 
       AND SALESHEADER.ParentAccountID = T1.ACCOUNTID
       AND T1.WarehouseID=1 )
```